# How does one project out the translations and rotations from a Hessian?

Tags: electronic-structure, quantum-chemistry

I've recently written a simple code to numerically compute the Hessian of some function (at a point). Most electronic structure packages will compute the Hessian and then project out the translations and rotations. I have tried to look up how one actually does this, but I can't find any good information really.

I feel like this should be pretty simple, so I feel a bit silly for not knowing how to do it, but if someone can provide some mathematical detail on how to project out the translational and rotational modes, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/441/retrieving-translational-and-rotational-modes. The link to the Gaussian website talks about the projection

Comment: I am not sure how the math would work, but I think it should be possible to generate a set of internal coordinates from the Cartesian coordinates of the atoms, then transform the Cartesian hessian matrix into the internal coordinate system, which will allow you to identify the trans. and rot. modes. Then you can again convert the hessian into Cartesian. Also, have a look at this paper: http://www.cchem.berkeley.edu/millergrp/pdf/120.pdf (J. Chem. Phys., 1980, 72, 99-112)

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti I think this actually answers the question, so I might try to implement it from there. There's a lot of extra stuff being described in this paper, so maybe someone will summarize in a nice way. If I figure it out first, I'll give an answer.

Comment: While converting the Hessian to internal coordinates is an interesting one, it is not how it is done in practice. In practice the translation and rotations are removed by going to the Eckart frame, which separates vibrations from rotations and translations. Those modes are then easily identifiable because their frequency is zero. I can post some python code to see how this is done if you would like

Comment: @CodyAldaz Isn't the Eckart frame for an equilibrium configuration just the same equilibrium configuration at the center of mass? I don't see how that will affect the eigenvalues the hessian.

Comment: I think this gaussian page answers the question very clearly: https://web.archive.org/web/20191229092611/https://gaussian.com/vib/

Basically, you do transform the hessian to internal coordinates. I will try this and answer the question here, though the gaussian link explains it as clearly as one could hope to really.

Comment: @jheindel that page is exactly what you want to do but I don't understand what you mean by transform to internal coordinates. That means a very specific thing to me and that is not what they are doing in that gaussian page E.g. the vibrations are in the Cartesian coordinate systems not the internal coordinate system (bonds, angles and torsions). Converting to the IC system requires extra effort e.g. [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/134595/26815)

Comment: @CodyAldaz They are constructing the transformation matrix from cartesian coordinates to internal coordinates. This transformation essentially projects out the external degrees of freedom. They are not diagonalizing the Cartesian hessian, but the hessian which is transformed to internal coordinates which forces exactly the six zero eigenvalues. So, it is true they are doing the displacements in cartesian coordinates (makes finite differencing easier), but they are not diagonalizing the hessian made up those derivatives.

Comment: @CodyAldaz So, the molecular coordinates never need to be in internal coordinates in order to diagonalize the hessian in internal coordinates. This is what I wasn't understanding.

Comment: +1 for the good question! It seems that the comments have helped you to find the place where you can get the answer, and that you're willing to write a simpler answer here on this site once you digest the information in those sources. I see there's a lot of back-&-forth discussion going on, which is great, but to avoid this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353643/avoiding-making-so-many-new-chatrooms-called-discussion-between-usera-and-use, I would suggest this room: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117652/spectroscopy-potentiology if the system tries to get you to switch to chat.

Comment: @jheindel Did you manage to make any more progress with this issue? By the way, you can reply here, but if the system recommends for you to move to chat, please follow [these instructions](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/268/5) to move this conversation to the spectroscopy chat room, rather than clicking the button which will create a new room!

Answer (score 4):

I've put some code online https://gist.github.com/craldaz/b38e1c951d515c807c67aac303406343

that demonstrates how one removes translations and rotations from the Hessian using the description you linked https://web.archive.org/web/20191229092611/https://gaussian.com/vib/

First you have to form the axes of inertia which is done in the function `eckart_frame`, then the basis of vibrations is formed in the function `vibrational_basis` and finally the hessian is projected into this vibrational basis in `normal_modes` to remove all the translations and rotations.

The axes of inertia are used in the `vibrational_basis` function to form the matrix TR (or D in the web archive) which contains all translations and rotation. The null space of TR is the vibrational basis, B, in the Eckart frame. The final projection to get the Hessian in internal coordinates is done using B

$$H_{int} = BHB$$

*Note that I am using the SVD and not the Gram-Schmidt algorithm the Gaussian archive uses. It's much easier to do.

Comment: Nice code. Does it handle linear molecules ? It seems that you always remove 6 external degrees of freedom, unless I am mistaken.

Comment: Cool! This seems like it'd be a great addition to `cclib` (e.g., as one of the calculation methods) since they already process Hessians.

Comment: What if I don't want the Hessian in internal coordinates, but I want the Hessian without rotation/translation in Cartesian? How do I manage that?